# Wordpress y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

Tengo una ecommerce hecha en wordpress y tambien para esa misma web quisiera crear un blog. Pero este blog lo quisiera crear con laravel y la estructura de este blog quisiera guardarla en la misma estructura de archivos de wordpress, podría realizar este procedimiento ? si es así, cuales serían los pasos a seguir para poder llevarlo a cabo.

Comment: Buen día Henry, el escenario está interesante y lamentablemente se escapa a los lineamientos del sitio. Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo funcionar considerando la documentación de wordpress y la documentación de Laravel. Por cierto, que no te sorprenda si tu pregunta es cerrada por ser demasiado amplia y/o basada en opiniones. Te siguero revisar este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que puedas preguntar de mejor manera. ¡Saludos y bienvenido a SOes! :D

Comment: cómo es la estructura de carpetas del servidor? onda `/var/www/html` , `/home/username/example.com` o `/public_html` 
tenes acceso ssh? es linux? apache?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1 - Wordpress no procesa lo que venga en la url si es un archivo o una carpeta en el servidor, esto significa que si creas una carpeta llamada "blog" en el raiz de wordpress, el servidor va a servir esa carpeta sin que pase por wordpress.

2 - Laravel tiene una carpeta "public" que es un bootstrap de la aplicación, los require y require_once los maneja a través de la estructura de directorios ej: `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`.

Así que una estructura posible es mas o menos la siguiente:

Suponiendo wordpress está en la carpeta default de apache2 (ubuntu)

```
/var/www/html    -> raiz del wordpress
├── wp-admin
├── wp-content
├── wp-includes
├── .htaccess    -> .htaccess del wordpress
└── index.php    -> bootstrap del wordpress
```

http://localhost/  <- homepage del wordpress

Y suponiendo que no tenes ninguna pagina/post con slug `blog`

http://localhost/blog -> daría error 404 y/o redirección al home de wordpress (dependiendo del theme)

Luego la app laravel está en otra carpeta
(ejemplo corriendo el [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) `/home/code/$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` )

```
/home/code/blog/
├── app
├── artisan
├── bootstrap
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
├── database
├── package.json
├── phpunit.xml
├── public             -> raiz de la app laravel
│   ├── css
│   │   └── app.css
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── .htaccess      -> .htaccess de laravel
│   ├── index.php      -> bootstrap de laravel
│   ├── js
│   │   └── app.js
│   ├── robots.txt
│   └── web.config
├── readme.md
├── resources
├── routes
├── server.php
├── storage
├── tests
└── webpack.mix.js
```

La forma de "crear" la carpeta `blog` dentro de `/var/www/html` y que ésta sea la carpeta `public` del laravel (sin tener que copiar archivos y hacer una ensalada) es mediante un [Enlace simbólico o `symlink`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlace_simb%C3%B3lico)

Esto desde consola se hace así:

```
$ ln -s /home/code/blog/public /var/www/html/blog
```

Ahora si vas a la url correspondiente

http://localhost/blog  <- homepage del laravel

En este caso tengo la app laravel dentro `/home/code/` pues apache/php necesitan permisos de lectura en las carpetas padre y para no hacer ensalada de permisos, declaramos a `/home/code/` en el grupo del apache que puede ser `www-data` (ubuntu/debian) o `apache` (red-hat/centos).

Podría estar en otra carpeta pero ahi hay que jugar un poco con los permisos y owner/grupo.

Si es hosting compartido o sin acceso SSH (consola) ahí ya hay que meterse a configurar Laravel para poder renombrar "public" a "blog" y que levante la app desde una carpeta extra, por fuera del public_html preferentemente y si no es posible armarse unos .htaccess.

Si el servidor te lo permite también podes crear el [`symlink` con PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.symlink.php).

Tener en cuenta que si luego en el wordpress creas una página con slug `blog` esta no se va a ver pues ya hay una carpeta "blog".